# how can I pass an id of view for a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

how can I pass an id of view for a controller?
My code:

Categoria View

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', {:action => "show", :categoria_id => (params[:id]),:controller => "produtos", :method => "index"} %></td>
```

Produto Controller method: index

```
def index
@produtos = Produto.find(:all, :conditions => {:categoria_id => @categoria.id})
```

I want to get the id of the category and list all products with that id

Answer (score 0):

As in your view you are passing `:categoria_id => (params[:id])` , you can get that in controller using `params[:categoria_id]`

Moreover, the query for finding @produtos can simplifies as (For Rails 3+):

```
@produtos = Produto.where(:categoria_id => params[:categoria_id])
```